# Adding Links to Buttons using Parse keys

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

So I am trying to open a link with a button using the query from Parse. So the query works since the image and heading do come up. Also the key "Link" do load since the NSLog shows them. Its just that every time the view loads, the first link in the list is automatically opened. I am just wondering why. I want it to load it when the button is pressed and not when the view is loaded. If any questions, I will try to answer them to clarify the problem. Thanks in advanced!

for(PFObject *homeObject in self.homeObjectArray){

```
UIView *homeImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, originY, self.featuredScrollView.frame.size.width, 300)];


//Image
PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[homeObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
UIImageView *userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:image.getData]];
userImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, homeImage.frame.size.width, 320);
[homeImage addSubview:userImage];

//Label
UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 325, homeImage.frame.size.width, 18)];
headingLabel.text = [homeObject objectForKey:@"Heading"];
headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
headingLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[homeImage addSubview:headingLabel];

//Link
NSString *urlString = @"";
urlString = [homeObject objectForKey:@"Link"];
NSLog(@"URLS %@ \n", urlString);
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
UIButton *linkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
linkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:userImage.frame];
[linkButton addTarget:self action:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[homeImage addSubview:linkButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
[linkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomthing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) doSomthing
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257429/adding-links-to-buttons-using-parse-keys"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: That would work for normal circumstances but for using with Parse.com, it needs to stay in the loop so it can iterate through the links. 
First image = First Link
Second image = Second Link

That kind of thing.